# Fix version conflict in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Error is in third and fifth line...

Answer (score 0):

> Change Third Line

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
```

> Change fifth line

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
```